# CRS not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a raster whose Layer properties is as follows:

```
    Driver
GDAL provider
GTiff
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
D:/STUDY/MSC/Thesis/GIS works/temp/LU_New_region.tif
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Authors=Sophie Bontemps ,Eric Van Bogaert ,Pierre Defourny 
Copyright=Copyright Â©UCL Geomatics, BELGIUM 1999-2010
Generate by=gdal_mean
process begin time=2010-12-23T09:49:37
process files=CL5_GLOBCOVER-L5_CLASSIF_2009_V2.3.20101220.tif
process finish time=2010-12-23T09:57:38
Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=220
STATISTICS_MEAN=111.55999946952
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=11
STATISTICS_STDDEV=76.782603856836
Dimensions
X: 5589 Y: 2967 Bands: 1
Origin
76.3157,34.5213
Pixel Size
0.00277774,-0.00277774
No Data Value
0 
Data Type
Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=45 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
76.3156519612749094,26.2797412081658877 : 91.8404507576846925,34.5213010630500889
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
```

I have another raster whose Layer spatial reference system is as follows:

```
 Driver
GDAL provider
GTiff
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
D:/STUDY/MSC/Thesis/GIS works/GAV_X_combined_final.tif
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=90
STATISTICS_MEAN=37.946288072175
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=29.945215505785
Dimensions
X: 2386 Y: 4079 Bands: 1
Origin
251326,3.20264e+06
Pixel Size
30.3773,-30.3786
No Data Value
-3.40282e+38 
Data Type
Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=45 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
251326.4686199999996461,3078724.4376099999062717 : 323806.8145299999741837,3202638.6342000002041459
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
```

They don't superimpose. On the fly projection is OFF.
I can see the layer extent is not near in both of them. Is it causing the problem ?

Comment: One is projected the other is geographic that has been incorrectly defined as WGS84 UTM zone 45, redefine the layer as WGS84 geographic and you'll need to turn on *on-the-fly projection* to get them to align.

Comment: @MichaelStimson which one is incorrectly defined as wgs84 utm45 ? first or the second ?

Comment: @AndreJ if I re-save the first one assigning the wgs84 utm 45N will it work ?

Comment: It worked thanks. Can you please answer this question so that I can mark accepted @AndreJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first raster has a wrong CRS. You see it from the `Layer extent` which has degrees as units where meters should be according to the UTM CRS.

First assign EPSG:4326 to it, then save it to UTM and another name.